# How do I print multiple lines after a for loop matches an if statement?

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to parse a large text document. I am wanting to extract information from this document by using this code,

```
enumerated_journal = ""
with open('journal.0028.txt', 'r') as file_object:
    for line in enumerate(file_object.readlines()):
        enumerated_journal += str(line) + "\n"      

for line in enumerated_journal.splitlines():
    if "jrn." in line.lower() and "username" in line.lower():
        print(line)
```

This code is finding the line in the text document that contains the two strings that I am using as filters. I am wanting to know how to print the lines that precede or follow this line for a set number of lines.

For example, if print(line) returns,

```
"Username: Christian"
```

I would like to print the lines before and after this line.

```
"User Data:"
"Username: Christian"
"Age: 23"
"Location: Texas"
```

I appreciate the help in advance! Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Is it always bounded to one line before and two lines after?

Comment: `("a" and "b" in "bc") == True`

Comment: @ rayryeng No, I would like to be able to specify how much before and after depending on the information I am looking for.

Comment: Is this amount constant or does it change depending when the `if` statement matches?

Comment: A little more work, but it might be worth reading each set of N lines into a simple class, check the members of each class instance to find the strings you are looking for, and then print all members of the instances that match.

Comment: The `if "jrn." and "username" in line.lower()` doesn't do what (I think) you think it does. The first bit (`if "jrn."`) is always `True`.

Comment: `read_journal_enumerated` is new to me. I have no idea what it is or what it returns. If its just your own helper to open a file, just use "open" in your example so we know what we are dealing with.

Comment: @tdelaney My apologies, I have updated the code to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @NPE Could you explain how I could achieve the desired effect of filtering a string line that contains two filters that must be true? I appreciate it.

Comment: You can do `if "jrn." in line.lower() and "username" in line.lower():`

Comment: @tdelaney That makes sense! If I am understanding correctly, you have to make two arguments for the and statement to work as intended, otherwise it just takes one.

Comment: Its the order of operation. If I add grouping to your original, you may see the the problem: `("jrn.") and ("username" in line.lower())` which is the same as `(True) and ("username" in line.lower())` and since you are doing  an "and" operation, A constant `True` can be dropped, so its the same as `"username" in line.lower()`. End result - you never looked for jrn.

Comment: Fantastic explanation @tdelaney! I will modify my post to the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading the entire file into memory as a list and enumerating, so all you have to do is use the current index into the list to grab other nearby lines. I changed your compare to a regex to be a little faster and came up with:

```
import re

with open('journal.0028.txt', 'r') as file_object:
    lines = file_object.readlines()

for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if re.search(r"jrn\..*username", line.lower()):
        for item in lines[max(i-2, 0):i+3]:
            print(item.rstrip())
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you for your time and your efforts @tdelaney

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `linecache` [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the indices instead (using `enumerate()`):

```
indices = [index 
           for index, line in enumerate(read_journal_enumerated('journal.0028.txt').splitlines()) 
           if "jrn." and "username" in line.lower()]
```

Afterwards, you could use these to print lines with `index + / - x`.

Comment: Hey @Jan, thank you for taking the time to help me out. I am afraid that I am not following your answer, would it be possible for you to explain it further? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This should get you some part of the way there:

```
numlinesbefore = 2
numlinesafter = 2
linesbefore = []
for line in read_journal_enumerated('journal.0028.txt').splitlines():
    if numlinesbefore = -1:
        if numlinesafter > 0:
            print(line)
            numlinesafter -= numlinesafter
        else:
           break
    if "jrn." and "username" in line.lower():
        for bline in linesbefore:
            print(bline)
        print(line)
        numlinesbefore = -1
    else:
        linesbefore = [line] + linesbefore
        if len( linesbefore ) > numlinesbefore:
            linesbefore.pop()
```